# How to insert javascript variables into a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var mylink = "http://website.com/page.aspx?list=' + a + '&sublist=' + b + '";
```

This doesn't work. Is there a simple way to insert these other variables into the url query?

Comment: Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to avoid breaking changes in the future.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By using the right quotes:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var mylink = "http://website.com/page.aspx?list=" + a + "&sublist=" + b;
```

If you start a string with doublequotes, it can be ended with doublequotes and can contain singlequotes, same goes for the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

In modern JavaScript standards we are using `${var}` :

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var mylink = `http://website.com/page.aspx?list=${a}&sublist=${b}`;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var mylink = `http://website.com/page.aspx?list=${a}&sublist=${b}`;
```

Copied from above answer.

**Do notice that it is not single quote.**

[image]

Comment: This answer should be in the comments of the original answer