# How to make a URL with javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, web, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am trying to pass a Javascript variable into a URL, but there is some sort of syntax error within it.

```
function initMap() {
  var jsonData = { $tourArray }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: jsonData.CenterLat,
      lng: jsonData.CenterLon,
    },
  })

  var kml = jsonData.KmlFile
  var src = 'http://www.example.com/KML/?= + kml'

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    map: map,
  })
}
```

The variable `var kml` is basically the kml file name which is stored on the server within the folder KML and I am trying to access that file in order to add a KML layer on my google map.

The URL syntax seems to be incorrect.

Comment: How to insert javascript variables into a URL :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734343/how-to-insert-javascript-variables-into-a-url

Comment: can you print what's their in kml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert javascript variables into a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734343/how-to-insert-javascript-variables-into-a-url)

Comment: I had checked that question before, but the solution doesnt work in my case, According to that my url should become "http://www.example.com/KML/?=" + kml; but this doesnt work as well .

Comment: The names stored in the kml files are like this "T12_Zentral_Schweiz.kml" .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed it.

```
var src = "http://www.example.com/KML/?=" + kml;
```

If you're using ES6, then template literals makes it even cleaner.

```
var src = `http://www.example.com/KML/?=${kml}`
```