# don't want popup menu in webpage when the page will refresh

Tags: javascript, css

I have a popup menu but I don't want it second time when I refresh the page.
I try some javascript but I don't get success.
if any video/code available please answer me.

Comment: Please post any code that is relevant to your question -- it will help posters to better understand the issue and provide compatible answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something close to what you need by using a Javascript Cookie.

First load : no cookie exist, you set it and display the pop up.

Other load : the cookie exists, you don't display the pop up.

Set a session cookie, so the cookie will be deleted when the browser is closed.

[How to use javascript cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

[How to set Session only cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196671/session-only-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this without using cookies and session is that. You can append a [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734343/how-to-insert-javascript-variables-into-a-url) variable to the url on page load event. using javascript like `www.xyz.com?firstLoad=ture`

Using the technique above you can check the variable availability on next time if variable is present you dont open menu , else you open . And on page refresh the variable on url remain Intact.

Comment: can you please tell in depth for me to understand OR you have any Example,article link....