# How to convert this HTML to a string?

Tags: html, href

I have a link that is currently a string. It looks like this:

```
"<h2>New Test</h2><br><a href='/map/create-new?lat=35.7&lng=-83.55'>Create</a>"
```

The above works, but when I try to insert variables into the spot where `35.7` and `-83.55` are then I end up breaking the link and it doesn't work.

I tried like this:

```
"<h2>New Launch</h2><br><a href='/map/create-new?lat='+ event.latlng.lat + '&lng='  + event.latlng.lng'>Create</a>"
```

The variables are `event.latlng.lat` and `event.latlng.lng`.

When I try it like this, then the href ends up only being translated to:
`map/create-new?lat=` so I know that something is wrong with my placement of quotes but I'm just not seeing the issue.

EDIT: just for clarification, it must be a string like I have. I am passing this into a component that I did not make and this is how it works.

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734343/how-to-insert-javascript-variables-into-a-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the other answers worked for me. I ended up having to install `jquery` and then used it like this:

```
var link = jQuery("<a href='#'>Create New</a>").click(function () {
    self.onClickCreateNewLaunch(event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng);
})[0];
```

And then just navigated to the page using the function.

Answer (score 0):

By using the right quotes:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var mylink = "http://website.com/page.aspx?list=" + a + "&sublist=" + b;
```

If you start a string with doublequotes, it can be ended with doublequotes and can contain singlequotes, same goes for the other way around.

This answer was found to this question.
[How to insert javascript variables into a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734343/how-to-insert-javascript-variables-into-a-url)

best way to use variables within quotes is like this.

```js
<a href=`/map/create-new?lat= ${event.latlng.lat} &lng=${event.latlng.lng}`>
```

Comment: The problem though is the link is already surrounded by double quotes. In your example, the double quotes aren’t there so will that still work as expected? The criteria is to have quotes around the whole thing and then insert variables inside

Comment: It should work. ``"<h2>New Launch</h2><br><a href=`/map/create-new?lat=${ event.latlng.lat}&lng=${event.latlng.lng}`>Create</a>"``

Answer (score 0):

You can not add or use variables directly in your markup (html) but you can solve it and get desired results by using javascript (code below):

```js
const customLink = document.getElementById("customLink");

var1 = 35.7;
var2 = -83.55;
customLink.href = "/map/create-new?lat="+var1+"&lng="+var2;
```

```html
<h2>New Test</h2><br><a id="customLink" href=''>Create</a>
```

Comment: I’m not sure this will work because the link only gets created when it’s needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use variables like this within a string.

```js
<a href=`/map/create-new?lat= ${event.latlng.lat} &lng=${event.latlng.lng}`>
```

Comment: Will this still work if my HTML is already surrounded by quotes?

Comment: It should work. ``"<h2>New Launch</h2><br><a href=`/map/create-new?lat=${ event.latlng.lat}&lng=${event.latlng.lng}`>Create</a>"``

Comment: I’ll give this a shot when I get home so I can accept your answer. That should be the solution though. Thanks!

Comment: So it for some reason didn't work. When I click the link it navigates me to here: `http://127.0.0.1:5173/%60/map/create-new?lat=${`

Comment: So it is working right, but your link is not correct. It is getting localhost because you didn't add your base URL before ``/map``.  like this: baseUrl = ``"http://example.com"``; then add it to the ``href`` before ``/map`` as ``"<h2>New Launch</h2><br><a href=`{baseUrl}/map/create-new?lat=${ event.latlng.lat}&lng=${event.latlng.lng}`>Create</a>"``